# How to fix 404 page while opening strapi /admin page?

Tags: strapi

I am using the Strapi **v3.0.0-beta.18.7** when I am trying to open the **/admin** pages I got **404** erorr page.

To run strapi I am using command:

```
 ../node_modules/.bin/strapi develop --watch-admin
```

Console log:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried port 8000. That is the default for the --watch-admin flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your version then use `strapi develop` in the beginning.

There will be text on the console before **Project Information table**

Check this text it will help.

Admin development at http://localhost:8000/admin/

Comment: thanks for answer, it works. Just for the clear how this happen to me >> I overwrite my Homepage /public/admin/index.html, which with 'strapi build' made permanent changes to webpack. So when ever I installed again the old bad webpack overwrite Page even with not existing page.